# Distinguish different values from datagrid Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I have the following code:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Print Ticket"
                             Width="100">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ticketId}"
                           Width="0"
                           x:Name="printTicketBlock" />
                <Button Content="Print Ticket"
                        Cursor="Hand" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The value of printTicketBlock is different everytime, and I would like the button to use that value. But I can't seem to get my head around how to do it. 
The id is retrieved from the database and is usually 1,2,3 etc.
But I would like for the value (which will be different) to be available to me.

Here is a screenshot of what the display will look like:

[image: Example screenshot of presented code.]

Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button inherits the templated item in the DataContext, you can get your object like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = (sender as Button).DataContext as MyDataObject;
    DoStuff(data.ticketId);
}
```

No need to do anything with the TextBlock i think.

**Edit:** It's not very clear what you want ("*I would like the button to use that value*" is extremely vague), if this is not what you are looking for clarify your question.